# Javascript function as object property throws is not a function error

Tags: javascript

I have a simple javascript where I define an object and a function as its property.
When I try to call the function from the object, it throws is not a function error

Here's my code block

```
var name = {
    firstName: 'Rahul',
    lastName: 'Sharma',
    fullName: function() {

        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
};

document.write('Full name is ' + name.fullName());
```

Throws error -

> Uncaught TypeError: name.fullName is not a function

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use a variable name other than "name". Or, even better, use `const` or `let` instead of `var` (or, if you're using Babel and don't want to change away from `name`, put everything inside an IIFE)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think in that direction.